# Request for new tag "checkinstall"

Tags: discussion

Currently there are 30 QAs mentioning checkinstall without a corresponding tag. Would be nice to have such a tag for faster reference and possible wikification.

Comment: Please don't tag a question just because an answer mentions it. If it's not in the question then the tag doesn't belong.

Comment: Thanks, will avoid this pitfall in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created it and tagged a couple of questions to get it started. I'll let you tag the rest :)

*edit*

Quite a few questions mention it as an answer, so just doing a search for "checkinstall" might be a bit misleading - especially if that's not what the asker was looking for.